# Terraform EMR on EKS virtual cluster error

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, amazon-emr

im trying to add emr on eks via the terraform blueprint,

I have added the following which creates adds the blueprint side successfully:

```
module "emr-blueprint" {
  source = "github.com/aws-ia/terraform-aws-eks-blueprints//modules/emr-on-eks/?ref=v4.31.0"

  eks_cluster_id = module.eks-oc.cluster_name

  emr_on_eks_teams = {
    emr = {
      namespace               = "emr"
      job_execution_role      = "emr-job-execution-role"
    }
  }
  tags = {}
}
```

Even though this is successfully i can see its created roles etc. It does not create a namespace called `emr` but does create an empty namespace called `emr-on-eks-spark`

I then create a virtual cluster via:

```
resource "aws_emrcontainers_virtual_cluster" "emr" {
  name = "${local.full_name}-emr"

  container_provider {
    id   = data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.id
    type = "EKS"

    info {
      eks_info {
        namespace = "emr"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When generates an error:

```
 Error: creating EMR Containers Virtual Cluster (oc-dev-data-science-emr): ValidationException: Unauthorized to perform read namespace on emr
│ 
│   with module.oc-aws-data-science.aws_emrcontainers_virtual_cluster.emr,
│   on ../../emr2.tf line 1, in resource "aws_emrcontainers_virtual_cluster" "emr":
│    1: resource "aws_emrcontainers_virtual_cluster" "emr" {
```

I thought it might be because the namespace doesnt exist and i needed to create it but even do that and re-running still causes the same error.

Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Have this exact same issue. Sad to see no one has answered it. Let me know if you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same issue.

The Terraform blueprint code does not include the step to '[Enable cluster
access for EMR on EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/setting-up-cluster-access.html)':

```bash
eksctl create iamidentitymapping \
    --cluster my-cluster-name \
    --arn "arn:aws:iam::my-account-id:role/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonEMRContainers" \
    --username emr-containers
```

This [Terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/aidanmelen/eks-auth/aws/latest/examples/complete) may be helpful for managing the aws-auth configmap, although I have not used it personally. I'm currently running the `eksctl` command via a `null_resource` provisioner.